# Non finitely based varieties of groups defined by finitely many variables

Tags: gr.group-theory, universal-algebra

A set $\Sigma$ of group identities is called bounded if there is $n\geq 1$ such that for any $(w\approx 1)\in \Sigma$, we have $w\in F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. A variety $\mathbf{V}$ is called bounded defined if $\mathbf{V}=Mod(\Sigma)$ for some bounded set $\Sigma$.

Question: Is there an example of a bounded defined non-finitely based variety of groups?

P.S. $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is the free group of rank $n$.

Comment: I think there is a better way to ask this question.  Let T be a "narrow" equational theory, with closure of T logically equivalent to closure of S, where S is an equational basis in group theory at most n distinct variables.  Does cl(T) have a finite basis necessarily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is usually called a *non-finitely based variety of finite axiomatic rank*.

Actually, one of the first examples of non-finitely based variety of groups has axiomatic rank two; [Adian proved](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=2442&option_lang=eng) that the following set of identities is independent:
$$
\{[x^{pn},y^{pn}]^n=1\;|\; p \hbox{ is prime}\},
$$
where $n\ge 1003$ is any given odd number. *Independence* means that none of the laws is  a consequence of the other ones.

Comment: Dear Anton Klyachko, thank you for the example. Would you please check your emails? I sent a message.

Comment: Sorry for this question, it may be comic: the example of Adian has axiomatic rank 2 which is smaller than the axiomatic rank of the variety of groups. can you give an example of axiomatic rank >2?